# BS4 Searching by Class_ Returning Empty

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I currently am successfully scraping the data I need by chaining bs4 .contents together following a `find_all('div')`, but that seems inherently fragile. I'd like to go directly to the tag I need by class, but my "class_=" search is returning `None`.

I ran the following code on the html below, which returns `None`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)  # this works fine 

tag = soup.find(class_ = "loan-section-content")  # this returns None
```

Also tried `soup.find('div', class_ = "loan-section-content")` - also returns `None`.

My html is:

```
<div class="loan-section">
    <div class="loan-section-title">
        <span class="text-light"> Some Text </span>
</div>
<div class="loan-section-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <strong>More text</strong>
            <br/>
            <strong>
                <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Dakar,+Senegal/" target="_blank">Dakar</a>,&nbsp;Senegal
            </strong>
```

Comment: Is this the complete HTML you are using? (at least, there are missing closing tags at the end)

Comment: Anyway, I've tried all the parsers - no problems, it returns the desired `div`. Please show the complete code you have at the moment. `text` is probably something different from what you show.

Comment: its working fine, idk why its not working for you

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick replies everyone. I saved exactly the html above to a file called testhtml.txt. Then I ran the code above between f.open() and f.close() but got (and still get) None. However, both of the lines provided by Hackaholic below worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
soup.find(attrs={'class':'loan-section-content'})
or
soup.find('div','loan-section-content')
```

`attrs` will search on attributes

Demo:
[image: Demo]

Comment: Both work in BeautifulSoup 4.1.0 and it also returns the element in question when it has other classes too, e.g. `<div class="loan-section-content hurz"></div>`. In BeautifulSoup 4.2.1 the issue is fixed and `find`-ing by `class_` works fine. Fortunately, the 4.1.0-solution continues to work in 4.2.1.